# Is it possible for a data frame to be expanded and restructured in a way that every single columns have pairwise in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

I have a data frame like this:

```
no.   id  age  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1
2   1830  24   2     1    3    8    5
3   4550  71   0     3    2    2    1
4   2760  43   4     5    8    3    2
5   3761  15   3     1    0    2    7
6   4410  72   1     2    2    1    6             
7   4580  22   2     1    2    3    4
```

Following is a syntax:

```html
dt <- structure(
  list(
    ï..no. = 1:7,
    id = c(580L, 1830L, 4550L, 2760L,
           3761L, 4410L, 4580L),
    age = c(51L, 24L, 71L, 43L, 15L, 72L, 22L),
    var1 = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L),
    var2 = c(2L, 1L, 3L,
             5L, 1L, 2L, 1L),
    var3 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 2L),
    var4 = c(3L,
             8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L),
    var5 = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-7L)
)
```

However, I would like to create a new data frame based on above data. The number of observation should stem from Permutation of every two columns. Thus, original columns have pairwise with each other. In the new data frame, the total number of observations is 7P2 = 7! / (7-2)! = 7*6 = 42.

That is, data frame that I want to have is like this:

```
dyad     no.   id  age  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
  1      1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1   
  1      2   1830  24   2     1    3    8    5
  2      1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1
  2      3   4550  71   0     3    2    2    1
  3      1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1
  3      4   2760  43   4     5    8    3    2
  4      1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1
  4      5   3761  15   3     1    0    2    7
  5      1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1
  5      6   4410  72   1     2    2    1    6             
  6      1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1  
  6      7   4580  22   2     1    2    3    4
     .                     .
     .                     .
         2   1830  24   2     1    3    8    5
         1    580  51   1     2    3    3    1
         2   1830  24   2     1    3    8    5
         3   4550  71   0     3    2    2    1
     .                     .
     .                     .
         7   4580  22   2     1    2    3    4         
         5   3761  15   3     1    0    2    7
         7   4580  22   2     1    2    3    4         
         6   4410  72   1     2    2    1    6
```

I hope to get great answer for this problem.

Best regards,

Leroy

Comment: Please use `dput` on your dataframe to give us exampledata.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are choosing per combination two rows, your result should have 84 observations.

Assuming that the column `no` is `1:NROW(df)` you can do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(no=1:7,id=(1:7)*100,age=21:27,var1=11:17,var2=31:37) #sample data

#create all combinations
combinations <- do.call("rbind",lapply(df$no, function(i) {
  matrix(c(rep(i,length(df$no)-1),setdiff(df$no,i)), ncol = 2)
}))

#choose the rows for every combination
res <- apply(combinations,1,function(startend) {df[startend,]})
#bind everything together
res <- do.call("rbind",res)
#add the dyad counting column in front
res <- cbind(data.frame(dyad = rep(1:NROW(combinations),each=2)),res)
rownames(res) <- NULL
```

Update: The combinations can be calculated faster using

```
combinations <- matrix(
  c(rep(df$no,each=length(df$no)-1),
    unlist(lapply(df$no, function(i) df$no[-i]))), 
  ncol = 2
)
```

On my machine its around a 5x difference.

UpUpdate:
You dont even need the apply function. You can make use of a nice indexing feature of dataframes in R. Instead of

```
res <- apply(combinations,1,function(startend) {
  df[startend,]
})
res <- do.call("rbind",res)
```

you could simply do

```
res <- df[as.vector(t(combinations)),]
```

and then go on with `cbind`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, @Jonas! I am just trying to apply what you taught to my data which has more number of observations (44) and variables (33). However, from the syntax $res <- apply(combinations,1,function(startend) {df[startend,]}) $, I have all NAs in each variables.  Could you explain why and what I should change?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can get rid of the `apply`. If the creation of the combination-matrix works, everything should be fine now. And it should be really fast now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gtools::permutations` to permute your `id` column (or `gtools::combinations` if order doesn't matter) and `tidyverse` to pivot and join:

```
library(gtools)
library(tidyverse)

gtools::permutations(nrow(df), r = 2, v = df$id) %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("dyad") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dyad = as.integer(dyad)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(starts_with("X"),
                      values_to = "id") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-name) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(df, 
                   by = "id") %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(dyad)
```

Note: if column order is important then you can reorder the columns with **dplyr >= 1.0.0** by adding a pipe to `` dplyr::relocate(id, .after = `no.`) ``

**Output**

```
    dyad    id   no.   age  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1   580     1    51     1     2     3     3     1
 2     1  1830     2    24     2     1     3     8     5
 3     2   580     1    51     1     2     3     3     1
 4     2  2760     4    43     4     5     8     3     2
 5     3   580     1    51     1     2     3     3     1
 6     3  3761     5    15     3     1     0     2     7
 7     4   580     1    51     1     2     3     3     1
 8     4  4410     6    72     1     2     2     1     6
 9     5   580     1    51     1     2     3     3     1
10     5  4550     3    71     0     3     2     2     1
# ... with 74 more rows
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(no. = 1:7, id = c(580L, 1830L, 4550L, 2760L, 3761L, 
4410L, 4580L), age = c(51L, 24L, 71L, 43L, 15L, 72L, 22L), var1 = c(1L, 
2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), var2 = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    var3 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 2L), var4 = c(3L, 8L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), var5 = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: It is super helpful. Thank you, @LMc.  But, can you little bit more explain the syntax, ' dplyr::relocate(id, .after = `no.`) ' ?   I tried to add the syntax after ' dplyr::arrange(dyad) ', but it does not work. The column order is important :)

Comment: Did you add the pipe? ``%>% dplyr::relocate(id, .after = `no.`) ``

Comment: thank you, @LMc ! I just missed 'no.'.  It works very clearly :)

Comment: You're welcome! If you found this or another answer useful please upvote and/or mark as answered: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)